# ¿Como elegir a un usuario de entre miles de visitantes no logeados?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, api

Hola tengo una página web en la que tengo un code ajax $post que lo que hace que cada vez que el usuario entra a la web esta produce una petición de refresco de enlaces que obtengo de otras páginas mías.

El problema es que recibo miles de visitas en la página que tengo dicho code ajax por lo cual sobresatura de peticiones a las otras páginas. Entonces lo que necesito es que de los miles de users no identificados y aparte anónimos elegir un user que haga la petición.

De antemano Muchas Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola T8kcontrol, bienvenid@ a [es.so]. Has de explicar más tu preguntta. no está claro qué intentas hacer. Un saludo

Comment: Marca una aletoriedad. O sino, que vaya contandolos y el numero X sea seleccionado.

Comment: Hola lois6b te explico un poco mas.. Mi web recibe cientos visitas cada segundo. Mi web tiene contenido que se pide a otra de mis web mediante un ajax $posts al entrar el user. El problema es que cada user nuevo que llega anda haciendo esa peticion a su vez este user si se mueve por la web a otra pagina hace de nuevo la peticion. Un ejemplo de code seria...  
$.post('urlmiweb/phpfile',{id: 'idposts',reflesh: true});
entonces siempre anda pidiendo y lo que quiero es que por ejemplo cada segundos uno de los cientos de usuarios que hay en la web sea el que haga esa peticion y no todos a la vez.

Comment: ¿Podrías generar un cron que cada x minutos o segundos llame al script de refresco? Así tienes el control total sobre cuándo y cómo se refrescan tus enlaces.

Comment: Hola Mauritano el tema es que debo hacerlo por ajax no lo quiero hacer por php o con clonjob

Comment: Hola GDP el tema es que como cuentas usuarios que no estan logeados? Como controlas que paso el time y aparte que de los usuarios que haya online elijas a uno? para que este haga el reflesco

Comment: Se me ocurre que en el servidor generes un número aleatorio de 0 a X, y en el cliente, con javascript, hagas lo mismo. Si coinciden, haz la petición. No es la solución que más me gusta, pero si no tienes posibilidad o no quieres hacerlo con un cron, debería funcionar.

Comment: Si las actualizaciones se hacen directametne desde ajax, sin código en el servidor ¿de qué le servirá al usuario/sesión X que el usuario Y haya obtenido la información de los enlaces? X seguirá sin tener la información... aclara bien lo que quieres y expon que código tienes, porque lo que explicas cada vez tiene menos sentido...

Comment: Si Mauritano ahora mismo tengo algo similar uso var Numberrand =Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1; if(Numberrand==2){$.post('urlmiweb/phpfile',{id: 'idposts',reflesh: true});}

Comment: Hola SJuan76. El contenido... se pide a otra de mis webs que se va actualizando en  time real  .... Eso ya en base se muestra en la web en cuestion para esta pregunta y se almacena en cache en un file por lo que el user al entrar si que ve info pero si no tuviese el $post no se actualizaria. Al hacer la peticion $post lo que hago ahi es que cada user pida una actualizacion de la info a la otra pagina mia bueno en verdad son mas de una pagina interrelacionadas.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo los comentarios te digo que no conozco una manera de hacerlo sin usar una base de datos para contabilizar los usuarios (Cosa que no tiene sentido porque para eso harías peticiones al server que es lo que no quieres)

Sin embargo te presento una posible solucion para arreglar tu problema:

Consiste en crear un script que se base en las matemáticas, y controlarlo todo por probabilidad, la probabilidad la puedes cambiar:

```
<script>
    //use window en lugar del método de jQuery para que sin importar dónde coloque este script este espere a que carguen todos los recuesos (incluendo jQuery) y funcione de manera correcta, de otro modo podrían haber fallos.
    window.onload = function (){
        let num = Math.round(Math.random()*100); //generar un numero entre 0 y 100 y guardarlo en una variable llamada num
        if(num==0){num = 1} //para evitar que sean 101 numeros y sólo sean 100
        if(num>=75 && num<=100){ //sólo hay 25 numeros que corresponden osea 25%
            $.post(tusParametros); //tu peticion post de ajax
        }
    }
</script>
```

Para este script se genera una posibilidad del 25% de que se haga la peticion pero lo puedes cambiar, de esa manera no todos los usuarios generarán la peticion ajax.

**Limitarlo a usuarios anonimos o no logeados**

Supongo que debes de tener un sistema de autenticación, no lo conozco pero al ser lo más comun las sesiones en php te recomiendo lo siguiente, si usas otro sistema me lo comentas y veré si puedo encontrar como implementarlo.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){ //algo muy simple pero es la idea
         require 'somepage.php';
    }else{
        require 'miScript.php';
    }
?>
```

En este caso si es un usuario incluiras el código el cual siempre realiza la peticion pero si no incluiras el código de la peticion que se basa en la probabilidad.

Para mi ejemplo `somepage.php`contendria la peticion que siempre se realiza para que los usuarios con sesion iniciada tengan el beneficio y `miScript.php` tendría solo el codigo que realiza peticiones al azar.

**¿Por que los archivos que contienen los script tienen extension .php?**
 -Si necesitas tener código HTML o PHP o JS puedes tenerlo en ese mismo archivo
 -Segun mis conocimientos es lo mismo hacer un require a un archivo .js, este obtendría literalmente el texto que hay en el

Comment: Bueno si encuentras una manera de Contabilizar los usuarios anonimos que no esten logeados y que a su vez haga uno de ellos la peticion cada segundo de los cientos de usuarios online que haya en ese momento. Pues si estaria dispuesto a implementar una consulta a la db.

Comment: Aparte otra cosa que acabo pensar y que ya pasa con mi code... que es que si hay 1000 usuarios online ahora mismo. con mi code digamos el 33% actualiza la info y con tu code aprox el 25% actualiza la info lo que yo  busco es que uno de esos 1000 usuarios sea el unico que actualice la info cada segundo y si ese user se fue de la web sea otro user el que actualice la info en el segundo siguiente.

Comment: Puedo hacer todo eso, pero eso implica cosas como long-polling para las actualizaciones (claro si quieres las mejores practicas), es algo extenso pero te puedo decir los pasos que tienes que seguír, (sin codigo ya que es mucho) ¿Quieres eso?

Comment: Podriamos intentarlo.Yo agradecido estaria.

Comment: Esta bien, tratare de ser breve, - Cada que un usuario no loggeado ingrese ejecutar una peticion ajax a un archivo php que hará lo sig: Consultar una tabla de bases de datos, donde tendras 2 campos ip y refresh, contar el numero de registros, (Con PDO o mysqli es facil seleccioans todos los registros y los cuentas), por cada por ejemplo 1000 usuarios contaras el numero de usuarios que tengan refresh en true, si por ejemplo hay 1000 usuarios debe haber al menos un usuario en true si no es así por probabilidad determinas si a ese usuario le daras el permiso del refresh  pero si los usuarios son

Comment: 999 y ninguno tiene true entonces por lógica a ese le obligaras a tener true, despues se inserta el registro del mismo usuario actual, en tu misma peticion para insertar el usuario se puede devolver si a este le toca el permiso de hacer refresh y de ahí hacer la peticion de refrescar los enlaces

Comment: Problemas que veo con tu code: 1º es que no se controla el tiempo en que esos mil users estan en la web porque si el user entro y se fue esa ip aunque tenga true no podra hacer el reflesco.
2º yo ahora en el index.php al comienzo de todo hago la consulta a la db para insertar la ip del user. Mas abajo ya donde estaria el body pongo el js del ajax $post que lo que hace es pedir a un file de la web que me de los ultimos 100  registros (ya que asi se controla mas) de los cuales cuenta los que tienen true en el reflesh y si la ip de ese user coincide con la ip true puede hacer el reflesh sino no.

Comment: si ningun user de los 100 limitados tiene true entonces. se le asigna true a ese user...
3º  El problema mas que veo con tu code que si siempre selecciono los ultimos 100 es que si por lo que sea baja el trafico varios de esos users  tendrian por obligacion true ya que el que antes tenia true igual no esta.¿como controlamos eso?

Comment: Asi mismo veo otro problema y es que si selecciono solo los ultimos 1000 pero llegaron 1000 users mas el user que acaba entrar ya no sera el 1000 sino el 1001 por lo cual no entraria dentro del conteo para true o no reflesh

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué no intentas hacerlo por tiempo y no por que una persona lo haga?
Me refiero a que, por Javascript llames al AJAX cada cierto tiempo, por ejemplo, 5 minutos.

```
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
      ...
    });
  }, 300000);
});
```

Así te evitas que se inunde tu servidor de peticiones y dejas de pensar en algoritmos complejos para saber que user va a refrescar tus links.

Que te sirva.

Comment: Porque si hago eso todos los users que entren en la web andaran siempre actualizando... contantemente mientras se mantengan en la web por lo cual esa es la peor opcion de las que me han respondido con perdon. porque ademas no creo que entendieses mi dilema no quiero que todos los users hagan la peticion sino uno de todos los que haya online en ese momento. Ademas el time que acabas de poner son 30 minutos y lo que requiero son 1 segundo aprox entre cada peticion pero de un  solo user.